# Calling macro with auto-incremented arguments

Tags: c++, c

Can any one please tell me why this following code giving he following answer

```
#define MAN(x,y) (x>y)?x:y
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 5;
    int k = 0;
    k = MAN(++x, y++);
    printf("%d%d%d", x, y, k);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT: 12 6  12  how?

Comment: I think it is converted to like MAX(++x, y++) ? ++x:y++

Comment: Suggestion: `void main(void)` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: @Subinoy almost, except the `MAX` part. :-)

Comment: So first increment in MAX(11,6), then second increment in ++x=12

Comment: What does `EXPERS` mean, and how is it a description of of your problem?

Comment: This piece of code give runtime error.
http://ideone.com/34rni2

Comment: @Barmar , I guess the OP was addressing us as "experts"

Comment: Just need to `int main(void)` and `return 0;` @Mox

Comment: obviously its "EXPERTS"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "call" to `MAN(++x, y++)` is substituted as

```
(++x > y++) ? ++x : y++
```

Both `x` and `y` are incremented once during the evaluation of the condition, after which their values are `11` and `6` respectively. The condition evaluates to true, so the ternary expression evaluates to `++x`. As a result, `x` itself is incremented once more, increasing its value to `12`. The ternary condition evaluates to `12`, which is assigned to `k`.

So, overall, `x` is incremented twice, and `y` only once, and `k` is assigned the value of `x` after both increments.

This is a common gotcha with preprocessor macros.

Comment: Super...! cannot beat experts

Answer (score 2):

Here, the MACRO expansion looks like

```
k = (++x > y++ ) ? ++x : y++;
```

Now, as per the semantics of the *ternary* (conditional) operator, quoting from `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.15, Paragraph 4, (*notice my emphasis*)

> `logical`-OR-`expression` ? `expression` : `conditional-expression`
>
> The second operand is evaluated only if the first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if the first compares equal to 0; the result is the value of the **second or third operand (whichever is evaluated),**...

So, based on the result of the evaluation of the first expression, **either** second **or** the third expression will get evaluated.

As per the values provided in above code snippet,  `( ++x > y++ )` is like `( 11 > 5)` which is TRUE, so the second operand will get evaluated.

If we break down the MACRO evaluation based on the variables involved,

- `++x` gets evaluated twice, once as the first operand, once as the second operand, so final value of `x` is `12`.
- `y++` evaluates only once, as part of the first operand. So `y` has `6`.
- the result of the ternary oreation is assigned to `k`, so `k` is `12`.

---

And, FWIW, it does not invoke UB (even if it appears so), because, (follow empasis, mine)

> The first operand is evaluated; **there is a sequence point between its evaluation and the evaluation of the second or third operand** (whichever is evaluated).

Answer (score 1):

So it happens like this-

`MAX(++10,5++)` which is

`MAX(11,6)` now then it look the `ternary operator` and finds `11` is greater, so

`++11:6++`, now the `12` is returned and we can see at last

```
x=12
y=6
k=12
```

Comment: Just to nitpick : `++11` is invalid, you know that, right?

Comment: Yeah I know that, just for explanation @SouravGhosh Da.